# exponent of the powerlaw distribution and Barabasi-Albert-Model; value of the exponent

Tags: python, exponent

I am to study the power-law distribution. I don't know how to calculate or measure and compare the value of alpha from the equation p(x)~cx^(-alpha).

[image: powerlaw]

1. I tried using the equation above to obtain the value of alpha, still couldn't find my way around way it.
2. From Barabasi article, for the citation or power grid date, how are the values of gamma obtained to be 2.3 and 4. Note, gamma can be used in the place of alpha from the equation.

Comment: What's the article you're referring to?

Comment: Emergence of Scaling in Random Networks Albert-La´szlo´ Baraba´si* and Re´ka Albert . I anticipate response from you   @Aziz

Comment: @yatu    You can also look at the question

Comment: This is not a math forum, you may have more luck at https://math.stackexchange.com/. Otherwise pls edit your question, it does NOT look like a python question.